# How to make titles bold based on date in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a WordPress site with static front page and it displays featured and recent posts....I am not using any widgets to achieve this, just using a custom home page template.

My requirement is to make the post titles bold based on date i.e., for instance I want the titles of the posts published today to be displayed in bold.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For a quickie, write a function in your functions.php in your theme folder which accepts the date.
Then compare the passed date if it lies between today's start time and end time. If yes, return true else return false.

In your custom template check the return value for every post in your loop and accordingly wrap the title in the bold tag